# household_objects_database remote access issue

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to access household_objects_database remotely following the tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database/Tutorials/Use%20the%20household_objects_database%20remotely%20from%20a%20Willow%20Garage%20server)

I launched the remote connection script

```
roslaunch household_objects_database objects_database_remote_client.launch
```

However when I try to run the following command

```
rosservice call /objects_database_node/get_model_list REDUCED_MODEL_SET
```

I get the error: *Unable to communicate with service [/objects_database_node/get_model_list], address [rosrpc://grasp.willowgarage.com:15432]*

It says in the tutorial that server might be down. However website (grasp.willowgarage.com) seems to be up.
I try to ping to port 15432 and here is the result

```
nmap -p 15432 grasp.willowgarage.com

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-11-02 13:02 EET
Nmap scan report for grasp.willowgarage.com (70.35.54.194)
Host is up (0.22s latency).
rDNS record for 70.35.54.194: gw.willowgarage.com
PORT      STATE    SERVICE
15432/tcp filtered unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.41 seconds
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Is this

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47318/household_objects_database-remote-access-issue/) by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 796 on 2012-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unfortunately, Willow Garage seems to block their database from external access for quite some time now and I think nobody ever updated the tutorial.

If you do not have a PR2 that has the database already installed, you have to set up your own database server. [This tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/household_objects_database/Tutorials/Install%20the%20household_objects%20database%20on%20your%20local%20database%20server) shows you how. I guess you've seen it already.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-11-02**:
Thanks for the answer. I've seen the tutorial, yes, but I didn't want to deal with the configuration details. Thanks again for clearing that up.

**Comment by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on 2013-03-09**:
@Lorenz
I have the same problem of @yygyt ,I have already installed my own database
, so what should I change in the command ?
and if it is still been blocked ?